# Understanding EC2 waiters

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following code that I'd like to understand:

```
DescribeInstanceStatusRequest instanceRequest = new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest().withInstanceIds([String of our instanceId]);
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
ec2.startInstances([instanceID string]);
ec2.waiters().instanceStatusOK().run(new WaiterParameters<DescribeInstanceStatusRequest>().withRequest(instanceRequest));
```

I was assured that this will start my ec2 instance and check that it it's running. I also understand that documentation states that `instanceStatusOk()` will poll until my desired state is achieved. How does the 4th line know what my desired state is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance status can be one of:

`ok | impaired | initializing | insufficient-data | not-applicable`

The [instanceStatusOK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/waiters/AmazonEC2Waiters.html#instanceStatusOk--) waiter method is a helper that creates a pre-configured waiter which can then be run to poll until the waiter determines whether or not the EC2 instance has the desired status (`ok`) or not.

It *knows* your desired status (of `ok`) because it's pre-configured with that status. You can create waiters for other status values but they don't have equivalent pre-configured helpers afaik (presumably because they're not as useful, in general).

Comment: Ok! So the person who gave me this was under the assumption that the "desired state" was the instance state of an ec2 `running | pending | stopping` and so on. So this is not that "instance" state but rather the "status" state. Alright! Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, they're confusingly similar in name. The state is something different that represents the EC2 instance lifecycle.